# flutter: unit testing dao in moor

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, flutter-moor

I've started unit testing the first time. I'm following tutorials of [resoCoder](https://github.com/ResoCoder/flutter-tdd-clean-architecture-course)

here is my test code where I'm mocking my dbManager class but I could not mock DAO's as they are auto-generated in moor and there is no setter method for them.

```
class MockDbManager extends Mock implements DbManager{}

void main() {
  RecipeLocalDataSource dataSource;
  MockDbManager _dbManager;
  setUp(() {
    _dbManager = MockDbManager();
    dataSource = RecipeLocalDataSource(_dbManager);
  });

  group('Search Food Table', (){
    List<FoodTableData> getFoodTable(){
      var list = [];
      for(var i =1; i <=5 ; i++){
        list.add(FoodTableData(id: i, name: 'item $i'));
      }
      return list;
    }
    var searchQuery = 'query';

    test('Should return foodTableData when query is successful', (){
      //arrange
      when(_dbManager.foodTableDao.searchFoods(searchQuery)).thenAnswer((realInvocation) async => getFoodTable());
      //act
      var result = dataSource.searchFoodTable('test');
      //assert
      verify(_dbManager.foodTableDao.searchFoods(searchQuery));
      expect(getFoodTable(), result);
    });
  });
}
```

I'm getting the following error

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'searchFoods' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: searchFoods("query")
```

I understood the error but don't know how to solve that.

Also, I'm getting a similar issue with preferenceManager class as well, where I'm having a getter for UserPrefs.

```
UserPrefs get user => UserPrefs(_pref);
```

when I'm accessing `_prefManager.user.name` for the test, it throws the same error. How can I tackle that as well?

Comment: Code is generated at compile time so, not sure what issue you are facing in mocking it. It should work like normal mocking. If you can share small sample then I can look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're missing a level of mocking, leading to the null exception.  Keep in mind the mocked class returns null for everything. You have to provide values for everything.

You've mocked DbManager, but not the foodTableDao field *inside* DbManager.

```
// I don't have your classes, so these are just my guesses at matching their interface
abstract class TableDao {
  String searchFoods();
}

abstract class DbManager {
  TableDao foodTableDao;
}


class MockDbManager extends Mock implements DbManager {}

class MockTableDao extends Mock implements TableDao {}
// ↑ Define this mocked class as well

void main() {
  test('Mockito example', () {
    final dbManager = MockDbManager();

    final mockTableDao = MockTableDao();
    // ↑ instantiate this mocked class which will be a field value inside dbManager
    
    // Mock the field access for dbManager.foodTableDao
    when(dbManager.foodTableDao).thenReturn(mockTableDao);
    //  ↑ You're missing this ↑ level of stubbing, so add this

    when(mockTableDao.searchFoods()).thenAnswer((realInvocation) => 'Cucumber');
    // ↑ define the stubbing at the mockTableDao level, not dbManger.mockTableDao.searchFoods
    
    expect(dbManager.foodTableDao.searchFoods(), 'Cucumber');
    // You can use foodTableDao field here, getting the mocked value as expected
  });
}
```

In your example above, you can't access `dbManager.foodTableDao` to set up a mock for `dbManager.foodTableDao.searchFoods()`, because `dbManager.foodTableDao` is null until you mock it.  So this line:

```
when(_dbManager.foodTableDao.searchFoods(searchQuery)).thenAnswer((realInvocation) async => getFoodTable());
```

was throwing the null exception, not the `expect` test below. (The expect test was never reached.)

---

The issue with `_prefManager.user.name` is the same I'm guessing.  You need to mock User class and provide a `when/return` of MockUser for _prefManager.user in order to provide another level of `when/return` for `_prefManager.user.name`.

It's like Mockception... you need to go another level deeper in your mocks. ;)

Comment: thanks a lot for teaching this. your explanation is so clear that I understood my mistake in a minute :)

Comment: I made the same mistake myself while writing out test code for the answer above, so I think I learned as much as you did.  Glad it helped :)